# Dynamic Content in emails - can I base a rule off of whether or not a field contains a value?

Tags: email, email-template, content, dynamic

I'm setting up dynamic content in an email for a client, and the logic that they provided is:

If 'Field_X' contains any value, display 'Content_A'
If 'Field_X' is empty, display 'Content_B'

My question is, can this be done, and how? Is there a wildcard of some sort that I can enter into the value box? Can I enter 'null' as the value?

Comment: is this visualforce template?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what a visualforce template is. I have coded all the HTML for the template and included a dynamic content area. I am working inside the My Contents folder to create the different content pieces, and I have created a piece of Dynamic Content where I am trying to set up the rules.

Comment: ok, can you post screenshot?

Comment: http://s92511587.onlinehome.us/sfmc-screen.gif

Basically, the two rules where I have entered 'null' in the value field - I just need to confirm if this will work to determine if the field is empty or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can check for null/not null within dynamic content areas (I've looked into it before and I couldn't back then). Instead of using a dynamic content area, you could just use AMPscript to call the individual content areas based on the same logic. This should work (apologies if there are inadvertent syntax errors):

```
%%[

    IF [Club_Code] == "005" AND NOT EMPTY([Cross_Sell_Disclosure]) THEN

        ContentAreaByName("Disclosure_CS-L")

    ELSEIF [Club_Code] != "005" AND NOT EMPTY([Cross_Sell_Disclosure]) THEN

        ContentAreaByName("Disclosure_CSonly")

    ELSE

        ContentAreaByName("Disclosure_empty")

    ENDIF

]%%
```

Comment: Any verification that this worked? @lhans